# Sorting a Pandas Dataframe by Date and Hour

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting, datetime

I've seen a few repeated questions like mine but none of the answers helped me out.
I'm having trouble in sorting this dataframe by datetime(the "Date" column format is yyyymmdd):

| Code | Date | Hour |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 20100301 | 15:01:04 |
| 3 | 20100202 | 09:15:59 |
| 2 | 20090401 | 15:25:27 |
| 1 | 20100202 | 09:14:16 |

This comes from a client's database and I know it's not by far the best way to store data, but there's not much I can do about it so I use the following code to "fix" it:

```
df['Date'] = df['Date'].astype(str)
df['Hour']= df['Date'].str[6:8]  + '/' + df['Date'].str[4:6] + '/' + df['Date'].str[0:4] + ' ' + df['Hour']
pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
```

So the dataframe looks like that (I know it'd be better to delete the "Date" table after using it but I have a good reason not to):

| Code | Date | Hour |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 20100301 | 01/03/2010 15:01:04 |
| 3 | 20100202 | 02/02/2010 09:15:59 |
| 2 | 20090401 | 01/04/2009 15:25:27 |
| 1 | 20100202 | 02/02/2010 09:14:16 |

I've tried the following codes (separately) to sort it but none seemed to work:

```
df = df.sort_values(['Hour'], ascending=True)
df = df.sort_values(by =['Hour'], ascending=True)
df = df.sort_values(['Hour'])
df.sort_values('Hour', inplace=True)
```

But all of these sort my df as:

| Code | Date | Hour |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 20100301 | 01/03/2010 15:01:04 |
| 2 | 20090401 | 01/04/2009 15:25:27 |
| 1 | 20100202 | 02/02/2010 09:14:16 |
| 3 | 20100202 | 02/02/2010 09:15:59 |

Does anyone know why isn't my sorting working? Maybe because of the datetime conversion? I can't even detect the pattern pandas used to sort my dataframe.
There's a lot more data in this dataframe and I'll gladly edit more into my post if necessary.

Comment: Your example looks like it is correctly sorted in ascending order on the Hour column. What should it look like? Also, it looks like Hour is not a datetime.

Comment: Yeah you're right, first convert it to pandas datetime format and then sort it. just do `df['Hour']=pd.to_datetime(df['Hour'],format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')` and then do sorting on this column

Comment: Nope I meant the modified `hour` column, the one where you've both date and time. pd.to_datetime supports both date and time as well.

Comment: Thank you both so much! @LazyCoder suggestion worked for me. I guess this happened because the default pandas format doesn't match my data, right?

Comment: @thiagopleasehelp Yes

Answer (score 0):

It is Hour that must be converted into time and not Date.

```
pd.to_datetime (df ['Hour'])
```